# Cómo enviar comandos en Python sobre un socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Tengo un problema con el codigo del cliente justamente en la ultima parte cuando estoy intentado encodear la informaciona enviar. me dice que el "result.encode". (el encode" no esta definida) no comprendo.

Quiero poder enviar comandos desde el servidor y que se ejecuten en el cliente, luego enviar dicha informacion nuevamente al servidor.

Estoy trabajando con python3.7

CODIGO SERVIDOR.

```
import socket

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, puerto))
    sock.listen(5)
    cliente, direccion = sock.accept()
    print("[+]Esperando conexion")

    with cliente:
        print("[+]Conexion establecida")

        while True:
            comandos = input("Shell->:")
            cliente.send(comandos.encode('utf-8'))
            data = cliente.recv(buffer)
            strdata = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(strdata)
```

COMPARTO CODIGO CLIENTE.

```
import socket
import subprocess

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000


def ejecutar_comandos(comandos):
    return subprocess.check_output(comandos, shell=True)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as servidor:
    servidor.connect((host, puerto))

    while True:
        data = servidor.recv(buffer)
        comandos = data.decode('utf-8')
        result = ejecutar_comandos(comandos)
        servidor.send(result.encode('utf-8')) ###AQUI EL PROBLEMA
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer, lo que contiene result YA es un objeto bytes. Y los objetos bytes no tienen el atributo encode. Ese objeto bytes, es una cadena codificada en utf-8? O que seria?

Comment: Ya lo solucione amigo. Lo que sucedia es que estaba intentando volver a codificar algo que ya habia sido codificado. Por lo que comprendi es que del servidor estoy intentando mandar el comando "dir" codificado, en el cliente lo decodifica y al enviar el resultado nuevamente al servidor no es necesario volver a codificar este resultado ni por parte del servidor volver a decodificar este resultado para verlo... basta con hacerlo solo una vez

Comment: Buen día @brandonsantibañez, si la pregunta fue resuelta por favor redacta una respuesta completa o en este caso que fue un error tipográfico podrías eliminar la pregunta. De esa forma ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El motivo real es porque [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) devuelve el resultado codificado en `bytes`

Por eso al intentar codificarla nuevamente con la siguiente línea

```
servidor.send(result.encode('utf-8'))
```

El programa no funcionaba correctamente, pero esto no quiere decir que no hay que decodificar la respuesta en el lado del servidor, como mencionaste, para enviar información entre un servidor y el cliente, es necesario que esté codificada, por lo que tu segunda pregunta se origina por haber quitado `decode` de la respuesta en el lado del servidor.

El código del servidor debe ser tal como lo pusiste en tu pregunta

```
import socket

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, puerto))
    sock.listen(5)
    cliente, direccion = sock.accept()
    print("[+]Esperando conexion")

    with cliente:
        print("[+]Conexion establecida")

        while True:
            comandos = input("Shell->:")
            cliente.send(comandos.encode('utf-8'))
            data = cliente.recv(buffer)
            strdata = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(strdata)
```

Y el del cliente quitando el `encode` porque la respuesta de `subprocess.check_output` ya viene codificada

```
import socket
import subprocess

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000


def ejecutar_comandos(comandos):
    return subprocess.check_output(comandos, shell=True)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as servidor:
    servidor.connect((host, puerto))

    while True:
        data = servidor.recv(buffer)
        comandos = data.decode('utf-8')
        result = ejecutar_comandos(comandos)
        servidor.send(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

El error procedia en que estaba intentado codificar nuevamente la informacion ya codificada. Me explico:

Enviar un comando desde el servidor al cliente, en python3x se necesita codificar antes de enviar. Para ello codifico el mensaje que esta en STR a bytes y por parte del cliente DECODIFICO el BYTE y lo paso a STR para poder ver el mensaje.

Luego de eso deseaba que el resultado mostrado en el cliente tambien pudiera verlo en el servidor y para ello (DONDE ESTABA MI ERROR) nuevamente intentaba primero codificar el resultado (por el lado del cliente) y enviarlo al servidor, y por parte del servidor decodificar para poder comprenderlo.

Bueno, esta ultima parte no era necesaria. Basta solo con codificar una vez el mensaje y ser decodificado una sola vez tmb.

COMPARTO CODIGO ANTERIOR CON CODIGO CORREGIDO.

```
while True:
        data = servidor.recv(buffer)
        comandos = data.decode('utf-8')
        result = ejecutar_comandos(comandos)
        servidor.send(result.encode('utf-8')) ###AQUI EL PROBLEMA###
        ##AQUI INTENTAA NUEVAMENTE CODIFICAR Y ENVIAR###
```

CODIGO SOLUCIONADO:

```
while True:
    data = servidor.recv(buffer)
    comandos = data.decode('utf-8')
    result = ejecutar_comandos(comandos)
    servidor.send(result)
```

Comment: Recuerda que mañana puedes marcarla como aceptada para que otros sepan que encontró solución

Comment: Buen día, la respuesta no es del todo correcta y analizando esta y tu pregunta siguiente vi que el problema era porque `check_output` codifica su respuesta. Puse una explicación en ambas preguntas pero creo que ambas se refieren al mismo problema. Saludos!